# Retention policy of archive/

Tags: postgresql

I have `archive_mode = on` and `archive_command = 'cp %p /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/archive/%f'`

What is retention policy of files under `archive/`? Will pg clean up it periodically or let it pile up until administrator panic and get involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retention policy is whatever you decide on and then implement.

Putting this under your control is what archive_command is for.  If you don't want to be in control and want PostgreSQL to do it for you, then use replication slots or wal_keep_segments instead.